# Prevent jQuery from unbinding events on element removal

Tags: javascript, jquery

**TL/DR: Is there any way to prevent jQuery from automatically unbinding events when an element is removed from the DOM?**

When you call `remove()` on an jQuery element, jQuery automatically unbinds all events for that element. For example, let's say I have the following:

```
var button = $("<button>Click me</button>");
$("body").append(button);

button.click(function() {
  console.log("clicked");
});

button.remove();
$("body").append(button);
```

If I click on the button, nothing is output to the console. One way to solve this problem is to bind the event to the element's parent like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "button", function() {
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

I'm trying to build a reusable control that wraps a jQuery element and adds new behavior to it. The solution of binding the event to the parent element doesn't work for me, because I can't be sure where the element is attached in the DOM and whether or not it will be removed. I don't want to bind the event to the document for performance reasons (there can be a lot of them). Is there any way to prevent jQuery's default remove behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `.remove()` use `.detach()`

```
button.detach();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PWtLc/)

[.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach()
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

> Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the
>   DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well
>   as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all
>   bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.
>   To remove the elements without removing data and events, use [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)
>   instead.

Comment: Wow, you answered my question in less than a minute. I'm not sure how I missed `detach` in the `remove` documentation. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Arun - if i use detach() method how to i recall again?

Comment: @sudhar what do you mean by recall?

Comment: if you wnat remove one element by using detach . that same element i want again

Comment: @sudhar you need to store the jQuery object reference in a variable/property